# sudo nohup and redirection

Tags: centos, sudo, nohup

Trying to figure out the correct Cmnd_Alias for the sudoers file

The command i which to run without any password is the following:

```
sudo /usr/bin/nohup /etc/init.d/axtty start >/dev/null 2>&1
```

The lines i have added to sudoers file is:

```
## Cmnd alias specification
Cmnd_Alias AXTOOLTTYSTART = /usr/bin/nohup /etc/init.d/axtty start >/dev/null 2>&1
Cmnd_Alias AXTOOLTTYSTOP = /etc/init.d/axtty stop
Cmnd_Alias AXTOOLTTYSTATUS = /etc/init.d/axtty status
Cmnd_Alias AXTOOLINTCTLSTART = /sbin/initctl start ttyp?
Cmnd_Alias AXTOOLINTCTLSTOP = /sbin/initctl stop ttyp?

## This will disable password request for the axtools commands
%sudoaxtools ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: AXTOOLTTYSTART, AXTOOLTTYSTOP, AXTOOLTTYSTATUS, AXTOOLINTCTLSTART, AXTOOLINTCTLSTOP
Defaults!AXTOOLTTYSTART !requiretty
Defaults!AXTOOLTTYSTOP !requiretty
```

The command in mention is ran inside a script (axopen), executed either by member of group sudoaxtools or root's crontab

**/usr/local/bin/axopen**

```
#!/bin/sh

SUDO=''
if (( $EUID != 0 )); then
    SUDO='sudo'
fi

echo -n "Checking for open connections"
while netstat -d | grep -q axel
do
  ((c++)) && ((c==900)) && break
  echo -n "."
  sleep 4
done
echo "done"

echo "Starting axtty service.."
$SUDO /usr/bin/nohup /etc/init.d/axtty start >/dev/null 2>&1
sleep 4
$SUDO /etc/init.d/axtty status
```

When axopen is executed på member of sudoaxtools, then it still prompts for password. I expect its because of the `>/dev/null 2>&1` pieces.

**Secondary**

The reason i'm using nohup is because the service for some reason will not start, when executed simply using

```
sudo /etc/init.d/axtty start
```

So if someone have ideas to fix that, it will be great as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up putting the nohup script in a seperate bash script.

**/usr/local/bin/axttystart**

```
#!/bin/sh

## Intermediate bashscript in order to sudo nohup properly
/usr/bin/nohup /etc/init.d/axtty start >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Then changed sudo'ers line containing the `Cmnd_alias` for `AXTOOLTTYSTART` to

```
Cmnd_Alias AXTOOLTTYSTART = /usr/local/bin/axttystart
```

The updated axopen script will instead for the sudoing the  nohup line directly, sudo the `axttystart` script

```
#!/bin/sh

[...]

echo "Starting axtty service.."
$SUDO /usr/local/bin/axttystart
sleep 4
$SUDO /etc/init.d/axtty status
```

Comment: Woops... You're correct, copy-paste mistake :-)

Answer (score 3):

You don't want the redirections as part of the sudo rule. /etc/sudoers contains the program that is executed, and the redirections happen separately (at the containing shell level) from the sudo command:

> (shell) sudo /usr/bin/nohup /etc/init.d/axtty start >/dev/null 2>&1

This calls sudo and redirects the output; sudo sees:

> (sudo) /usr/bin/nohup /etc/init.d/axtty start

Change this sudoers line:

```
Cmnd_Alias AXTOOLTTYSTART = /usr/bin/nohup /etc/init.d/axtty start >/dev/null 2>&1
```

to:

```
Cmnd_Alias AXTOOLTTYSTART = /usr/bin/nohup /etc/init.d/axtty start
```

Comment: The redirect is meant to handle the nohup output, thats why i have it. If i Sudo the script itself, will i the. Have to sudo the lines inside the script?

Comment: Leave the redirection in the script but take it out of sudoers.